# Threading from within a class with static and non-static methods

Tags: multithreading, oop, thread-safety

Let's say I have

```
class classA {

    void someMethod()
    {
    Thread a = new Thread(threadMethod);
    Thread b = new Thread(threadMethod);
    a.Start();
    b.Start();
    a.Join();
    b.Join();
    }

    void threadMethod()
    {
    int a = 0;
    a++;
    Console.Writeline(a);
    }
}

class classB {

    void someMethod()
    {
    Thread a = new Thread(threadMethod);
    Thread b = new Thread(threadMethod);
    a.Start();
    b.Start();
    a.Join();
    b.Join();
    }

    static void threadMethod()
    {
    int a = 0;
    a++;
    Console.Writeline(a);
    }
}
```

Assuming that in classA and classB, the contents of threadMethod have no effect to anything outside of its inner scope, does making threadMethod in classB static have any functional difference?

Also, I start two threads that use the same method in the same class. Does each method get its own stack and they are isolated from one another in both classA and classB?
Does again the static really change nothing in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case there is no functional difference. Each thread gets it's own stack

Answer (score 3):

Methods don't have stacks, threads do. In your example `threadMethod` only uses local variables which are always private to the thread executing the method. It doesn't make any difference if the method is `static` or not as the method isn't sharing any data.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can be a little more clear. It doesn't matter if the function is declared static or not in most languages. Each thread has its own private statck.

Answer (score 1):

Each thread would get it's own stack.  There is no functional difference that I can tell between the two.

The only difference (obviously) is that the static version would be unable to access member functions/variables.