# Will my static method return a new EF context to every object that calls it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, object, static

Say that I have a WCF service that creates a separate instance of this RuleController on every WCF call:

```
public class RuleController
{
    private PresenceEntities _context;

    public RuleController()
    {
        _context = ContextCreator.GetEFContext();
    }
 }
```

Here is ContextCreator:

```
public static class ContextCreator
{
   public static PresenceEntities GetEFContext()
   {
     // Retrieve database configuration
     var modelFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ModelFilePath"];
     var connectionProvider = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionProvider"];
     var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];

     var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
     builder.Metadata = modelFilePath;
     builder.Provider = connectionProvider;
     builder.ProviderConnectionString = connectionString;

     var edmConnectionString = builder.ToString();
     return new PresenceEntities(edmConnectionString);
   }
}
```

Will each instance of RuleController get its own instance of entity framework context if I use a static method in this way?
I thinking yes since the reference to _context is held in RuleController, but I am not 100% sure.

Edit: Amended GetEFContext method to include the part where the connection string is built.

Comment: Yes it will get its own instance since you are using new PresenceEntities.

Comment: Yes, it's obvious with this code `return new PresenceEntities`

Comment: Thanks. But then it's probably bad practice anyway due to thread safety. The connection string is created using StringBuilder over 6 lines of code which I omitted from the example to save space. I figure that part risks not being thread safe.

Comment: I've amended the question to include the StringBuilder part as it may be relevant to thread safety. Any takes on this aspect?

Comment: According to the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524524/how-does-static-code-run-with-multiple-threads ...it looks like GetEFContext() above should be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will, because of

```
    public static PresenceEntities GetEFContext()
    {
        var edmConnectionString = [connection string here]
        return new PresenceEntities(edmConnectionString); //THIS LINE !!
    }
```

here you just create a new instance on every call.